# Getting segmentation fault when using double pointer

Tags: gcc

I trying to insert a node at the tail end of a linked list. But when I am moving the tail pointer to point to the new node I am getting an error of segmentation fault.

Also I am not able to print the current value of the tail's next value, which should be NULL.

I am using gcc in mac enviroment.

```
 void insert_tail(int val,struct node **tail)
 {
    struct node *new_node=NULL;
    new_node=malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->data=val;
    //printf("%p",(void*)*(*tail)->next);
    *(*tail)->next=*new_node;
    *tail=new_node;
 }
```

I am not getting any error when I run the same code on Visual C.

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your `struct node` definition, but this line:

```
*(*tail)->next=*new_node;
```

Almost certainly has too many dereferences in it.  Something like:

```
(*tail)->next = new_node;
```

Would be more normal, for a `struct node` that looks something like:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: I have changed the code but still I am getting the error Segmentation fault:11. It comipiles fine but at he run-time I get this error : void insert_tail(int val,struct node **head,struct node **tail)
{
        struct node *new_node=NULL;
        new_node=malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
        new_node->data=val;
        //printf("%p",(void*)*(*tail)->next);
        (*tail)->next=new_node;
        *tail=new_node;
        if(*head==NULL)
                *head=*tail;
}

Answer (score 1):

You are not dereferencing correctly:

```
*(*tail)->next = *newNode;
```

which is the same as

Should be:

```
(*tail)->next = newNode;
```

Or

```
(**tail).next = newNode;
```

Now your next is a pointer, so dereferencing the newNode, is not accurate, bc dereferencing it and assigning it to a pointer, will cast the bytes to a pointer, and read it as a memory address, segment fault(different size, bad memory addr, etc).